# Runtime-only properties

Tags: python

What is the best option for creating Blender properties that are only needed at run-time? My scene elements contain binary data that is temporarily converted into Blender properties when a window opens (to draw them and allow the user to manipulate them).

I currently have these properties defined as part of the operator that generates the window, which is working. But the window itself needs to contain buttons (secondary operators). These secondary operators will need to manipulate the properties as well, and I don't believe there is a safe way to communicate between operators like this. So its looking like I need to place them somewhere accessible to all of the operators.

Is there a good place to attach these types of properties? The data does not need to be saved with the Blend file or user preferences - it is only used while this window is active. I'm currently planning to define them into a sub-group of the user preferences, but I'm hoping there is a better alternative.

Comment: Even if there is no good answer, I would love some opinions and/or advice on how to deal with this kind of situation. Where would **you** put them? Is it best to add this type of data to the add-on preferences data? Or maybe there is a simple way to define Blender properties without attaching them to any scene objects - something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Meant to mention. Would you consider window manager properties "runtime".  They exist for the session and IIRC are friendlier with restricted context.  `screen` is also an ID object to consider if popping up a new window.

Comment: By "runtime", I meant data that doesn't need saved. I haven't tried attaching properties to the window manager or screen objects. If they are accessible globally, then it might be what I've been looking for. Thanks! Btw, your comment is a good answer if you want to copy & paste it as one.